# How to import SignalR in Angular2 component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr

I am using angular-cli to scaffold my Angular2 application.

Below is the excerpt from my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    // ...
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "signalr": "^2.2.1"
    //...
},
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.39",
    "@types/signalr": "^2.2.33"
    //...
}
```

My `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import "signalr";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
    constructor() {
        console.log($);
    }
}
```

Now I get the below error from SignalR saying jQuery is not added, but I have imported it in the line above:

> Error: jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before
>   the SignalR client JavaScript file.

If I comment out `import "signalr";` jQuery gets loaded correctly. What is happening here? Why does SignalR say jQuery is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue this way:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
require('signalr');
```

Signalr has dependency on `window.jQuery`. For some reason `import $ from 'jquery'` doesn't set `window.jQuery`. That's why need to do it explicitly.